# What are the advantages of having more than one bike?

Tags: bike-selection

I have decided to keep my Norco Yorkville even though I weigh 265 pounds.
That is well over the manufacturer's limit even without cargo like groceries. I have just upgraded the rear wheel due to the original breaking spokes. Next year the front wheel gets the same treatment.
If I got a fat bike it could be relegated to cargo duty with the added bonus of being able to ride in the snow. I live in Canada and
riding my bike was an adventure today.

What I want to know is if there are other advantages to having two bikes.

Comment: They make the garden tools even harder to access.

Comment: On a day to day basis, a fat bike is probably not a great idea. The gearing is pretty low for getting around town in decent conditions, and decent fat bikes are quite pricey. You might want to look more in the touring category -- the long haul trucker is designed for 300+ lbs rider+cargo. That being said, most people who are in your weight group ride whatever they can and deal with it, with better luck with more tough stuff -- rigid mountain bikes are a decent choice.

Comment: You've already described an advantage of having a second bike: you could have something that's more suited for riding in snow than your current bike. Before spending money on a fatbike, though, you should consider putting winter tyres on your existing bike. There are plenty of questions on this site about cycling in snow, and your local bike shop should be able to give you good advice, even if it's not where you bought your current bike.

Answer (score 6):

Rule 12 says that you should aim to own N+1 bikes, where N is the number you have now.  While that's completely tongue-in-cheek, there's some merit to having gear fit for purpose.

For example I have a fast road bike, which is uncomfortable in the rain and useless for carrying stuff.  I also have a 20" folder with carriers and mudguards/fenders, which is okay for moving things, towing a trailer, and works well in the rain.  But fast it is not.

The advantages of multiple bikes is **flexibility**

- Each can be set up for specific types of riding
- You can have a dedicated rain bike without having to add stuff
- Spare bike to ride if one is down for some reason
- Spare bike to offer to other people if they visit

The disadvantages are

- Extra cost - bikes aren't as expensive as cars, but aren't generally free either.
- Storage space - you can only ride one at a time, the rest will be stored somewhere.
- Upkeep - more bikes means more things to maintain and service, but your mileage is spread over more things.
- Records - you will need to keep better records over what was changed when, and how much mileage a bike has done.  I use strava for this.

---

In your case, the bike might be "over the recommended load" but you're working on that BY riding.

If you find that the bike is not performing to your needs then an additional/replacement bike might help.  This is different from you not performing as expected!

What would a fatbike do for you that your current bike doesn't?  It would likely go slower, weigh more, be harder to climb grades, and tubes/tyres are expensive.  On the plus side it would "float" over sand snow and loose dirt better, but it is not necessarily going to be any stronger or tougher than your existing bike.

You're only 20 kilos heavier than me, and you've already uprated the rear wheel.  I'd suggest riding it while you work on your fitness, and plan on a replacement bike in a couple years.

Comment: I am definitely overweight  but have to look at it as something to be managed not beaten. I was hit by a truck. Aside from broken bones I have several herniated disks. I am not whining though. Getting my Norco was the best thing I have done in a long time. Five kilometers minimum a day rain or shine before breakfast. That is about twelve hundred K from April to December. That is guesstimated. The real total is probably much higher.

Comment: This is to be added on to my last comment. Moose bikes of Canads has Fat bikes meant for bigger riders. I will have to learn how to post pics here as their Fat bike 1 2018 is pretty and gnarly looking at the same time. Free shipping as well. Getting the bike means I could ride this Winter and so be in better shape in the Spring. Training indoors just isn't for me.